# NGINX - Why can I bypass password authentication?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, .htpasswd, apache-utils

I have a NGINX server and I use Apache-utility's for password requirement (.htpasswd). It MOSTLY works fine. The following this work fine:

```
example.com/admin
example.com/admin/
example.com/admin/index
```

but...
When I type `example.com/admin/index.php` and don't type any password at all and press "abort" the server show's the index.php (without any CSS or JS files). I think my PHP-FPM is the problem. Please take a look:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}

location /admin {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /admin/.htpasswd;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass            127.0.0.1:9000;
    include                 fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html), but basically your authentication applies to `location /admin` and the `.php` files are processed by `location ~ \.php$`.

Comment: I see. But how do I fix that? I have no clue.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the last two locations in your question:

```
location ^~ /admin {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /admin/.htpasswd;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        include       fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Adding the `^~` modifier makes the `location ^~ /admin` block take precedence over the other regex blocks (specifically the existing `location ~ \.php$` block). So the authentication rules are uniformly applied to any URI beginning with `/admin`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

To avoid breaking PHP, the `location ~ \.php$` block is duplicated within the `location ^~ /admin` block to process URIs that begin with `/admin` and end with `.php`.

Comment: Nice. The the bug is now fixed. But now he always says 403 Forbidden. I checked the dir permissions, but there all right.

Comment: 403 may be caused when the URI is a bare directory (like `/admin` or `/admin/`) and no `index` or `try_files` rule exists to resolve it. You might want to look at adding an `index` or `try_files` into the `location ^~ /admin` block to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: I tried but still 403. Even when I point the URI at the file. Do you have an Idea why?

Comment: Did `auth_basic` work before? This is probably an unrelated problem. By the way, `auth_basic_user_file` takes a pathname and not a URI. `/admin/.htpasswd` looks suspiciously like a URI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113609/discussion-between-manuel-becker-and-richard-smith).